# Contar numeros repetidos en un array y abstraer solo repeticiones

Tags: typescript

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual cuenta las repeticiones de un vector de tiempos

```
function Repeticiones(ct: string[]) {
        let resumido: number[] = [];
        var repetidos: {
            [x: string]: number;
        };
        repetidos = {};
        ct.forEach(function (numero) {
            repetidos[numero] = (repetidos[numero] || 0) + 1;
            
        });

        return repetidos;
}
```

El resultado que imprime es el siguiente

```
{
  '1:47:59 p. m.': 2,
  '1:47:58 p. m.': 1,
  '1:48:00 p. m.': 3,
  '1:48:01 p. m.': 3,
  '1:48:02 p. m.': 4,
  '1:48:03 p. m.': 8,
  '1:48:04 p. m.': 8,
  '1:48:05 p. m.': 5,
  '1:48:06 p. m.': 9
 }
```

Requiero solo del resultado un vector con valores   `[2,1,3,3,4,8,8,5,9]`

ha intentado agregar la siguiente linea para abstraer solo los contadores pero me quedan repetidos.

```
resumido.push(repetidos[numero])
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un Map, en lugar de un objeto "normal", para asegurarte el orden en el que se te devuelven los valores, :

```js
let prueba = ['a','b','c','a','c','d','a','d'];

function Repeticiones(ct) {
  var repetidos = new Map();

  ct.forEach(function (numero) {
      if (repetidos.has(numero)) {
        console.log(numero);
        repetidos.set(numero, repetidos.get(numero) + 1);
      } else {
        repetidos.set(numero,1);
      }
  });
  console.log('Tenemos',Array.from(repetidos.entries()).toString());
  return Array.from(repetidos.values());
}

console.log('Resultado',Repeticiones(prueba).toString());
```

Si el orden no te importa demasiado, puedes simplemente usar Object.values():

```js
let prueba = ['a','b','c','a','c','d','a','d'];
function Repeticiones(ct) {
  
  var repetidos = {};
  ct.forEach(function (numero) {
      repetidos[numero] = (repetidos[numero] || 0) + 1;
  });

  return Object.values(repetidos);
}

console.log(Repeticiones(prueba));
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado la recomendación  de Object.value, gracias por la colaboración Pablo Lozano